# Latex file not compiling in normal mode anymore

Tags: compiling

My latex file used to compile in normal mode. I compiled it in fast mode once, now it won't compile in normal mode again. It comes up with many errors, nearly all of which are `undefined control sequence`, except the second error which is `Missing \begin{document}`. It's a very large document with many classes and errors. It's a document template for a phd thesis, I don't think I would be instructive for me to post any latex code at this point, as I have no idea of the source of the problem.

The first two error messages are below. Following this, all the other error messages are of the same form as the first one.

[image]

Comment: how should anyone be able to help you if you not even give the exact error message?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many errors you get. Concentrate on the first, and show this correctly formatted, copy it from the log-file.

Comment: I apologise for the incorrect formatting, just trying to get the info across as efficiently as possible at this point.

Comment: you are hiding more information than you are showing.But start by deleting your aux file (overleaf has a bin icon to delete all cached files)

Comment: It's all good now. I made a copy of the file and it compiles fine...